# How to replace second occurence of pattern in Java?

Tags: java, regex

I have SOAP data with strings as messageBody present. I want to search second occurrence of "messageBody"(without quotes) pattern. I have tried below code for matching the pattern, but it did not worked :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println(from3rd("harsh harsh"));
}

private static Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(/[^/]*){2}harsh([^/]*)");

public static String from3rd(String in) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(in);

    if (m.matches())
        return m.group(2);
    else
        return null;
}
```

Comment: can provide an Input Output please?

Comment: Note that `.matches()` will require the full string match. Try with `find()`.